# Android Wearable Message API does not work at all

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, google-play-services, adb

I tried some [basic communication tutorial](https://github.com/PaulTR/AndroidDemoProjects/tree/master/WearMessageApi) between mobile(handheld) and wearable but it doesn't work at all. Whenever I check the result of sendMessage, it says `SUCCESS` but receiver is never called.

I also changed deprecated `com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER` to `com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED` and `com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED` but it still not working.

Does this log relevant to this phenomenon?
`06-04 23:34:00.625 2789-2805/com.ptrprograms.wearmessageapi W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9080000 but found 8701534`
(However, the only wearable I have supports Google Play Service up to 8.7.01 and I can't download SDK for 8.7.01 from anywhere in this world)

Comment: I finally managed to solve the problem. I'll publish the summarized answer as soon as possible, with github repository of working code :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because the app never called GoogleApiClient's connect method such as `googleApiClient.connect()` and `googleApiClient.blockingConnect()`. However, while investigating the issue, I created some [*working* skeleton app for Android Wearable Messaging API](https://github.com/kcy1019/AndroidWerableMessagingAPI-Tutorial). *I also resolved the outdated warning by setting *Play-Service-Wearable*'s version into "7.5.0".